# Adding Certificate to Azure Self-hosted Gateway Image

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have some troubles working with the azure api management self-hosted gateway, what happens is that the self-hosted gateway cannot communicate with the apim because of ssl handshake verification, according microsfot doc I should add my custom certificate, but the doc does not show the steps to be applied.

how do I add a custom certificate in the docker base image that provides azure?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, by modifying the docker image that provides azure:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-api-management/gateway:latest
USER root
COPY customdomain.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/apim.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates
USER 1001
```

Comment: Root/CA certificate support for self-hosted gateways is in the works. Meanwhile this is the right approach.